# Qual a diferença entre FormsAuthentication createPersistentCookie true ou false?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Em uma aplicação ASP.NET Web Forms que usa FormsAuthentication no *Login* gostaria de saber:

1. Qual a diferença em usar FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage com createPersistentCookie true e false?
2. O que muda no comportamento da aplicação?
3. Tem vantagens ou desvantagens entre um e o outro?

Answer (score 1):

quando o createPersistentCookie é **false**(padrão), o cookie de atenticação é um cookie de sessão e será perdido quando o navegador for fechado. Já no caso em que for **true**, o cookie será mantido entre múltiplos acessos ao navegador até que chegue sua data de expiração(CookieTimeOut) ou seja removido.

Acredito que a vantagem de um modo ou outro depende do comportamento que que ser passado em sua aplicação para o usuário. No caso do uso do cookie persistente(true) a aplicação irá "lembrar" do acesso mesmo que o usuário feche o navegador, quando acessar novamente já estará logado. Isto é bem interessante pois se sua aplicação não tem a criticidade de uma aplicação bancária, por exemplo, permite que o no outro dia que o usuário acessar o site ele já esteja autenticado e não precise entrar as credenciais novamente, isso é bem bacana e confesso que adoro sites que fazem isso ^^.

As desvantagens estão relacionadas ao uso de cookies de forma geral, o navegador precisa estar habilitados a utiliza-los, limite de tamanho de cada cookie, quantidade de cookies no navegador, e existem algumas questões de segurança, veja [aqui](http://wstevanuz.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/createpersistentcookie-in-role-manager.html)